# ListView DragDrop doesnt work on new project in VS2013

Tags: wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

This is a really strange problem, I have a listview that I want to drop files onto, I know how to get the file info etc, and bizarrely I actually had it working fine, but then it seemed to just stop.

I have tried creating a new project with just a listview object, allowdrop=true, dragenter/drop events created, dragenter contains e.handled=true and e.effects = effects.none.

but the events just don't fire, I have a project that was created on an earlier version of VS, and this works fine !!

here is the xmal

```
<Window x:Name="mainWin" x:Class="droptest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaders" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="ImageList" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="204" Margin="65,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="374" DragEnter="ImageList_DragEnter" Drop="ImageList_Drop" DragOver="ImageList_DragOver" DragLeave="ImageList_DragLeave">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaders}">
                    <GridViewColumn/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and here is the code

```
namespace droptest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void ImageList_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }

        private void ImageList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ImageList_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }

        private void ImageList_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void ImageList_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }

        private void ImageList_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
        }


    }
}
```

I don't think I am doing anything wrong, in fact I am sure I aren't, as I had it working..

any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your DragEnter event handler is borken, it won't let any of the other events fire.  You said nothing at all about how you initiate the drag, it matters.

Comment: hi Hans, thanks for the comment, can you elaborate a little, i don't understand what you mean ? how is it broken ?

Comment: if i put break points in all the events, it doesn't reach any of them ?

Comment: DragEnter is fired first, it decides if your list view is a candidate for the drop at all.  What you are supposed to do is look at the dragged object through DragEventArgs.Data and decide if you know how to handle it.  Like giving the okay if it is text but not if it is an image or anything else.  You give the okay by assigning e.Effects to a value *other* than None.  You still didn't explain how you start the drag so it would be just blind guessing why the DragEnter event doesn't fire.

Comment: ahh ok, I am dragging images, pdf, pps files for a digital signage package from explorer. i used this in my main program

String[] dropItems = (String[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

and it worked fine, but then just stopped working, that is what i don't understand. if i put a break point in each of the events, non of them fire..